# PHP Colon syntax for control structures convertor

Tags: php, syntax

I would like to ask is there any software or script able to do conversion from
Colon syntax to curly brackets syntax?
From

```
if ($value):

endif;
```

To

```
if ($value) {

}
```

I am using Netbeans IDE, when I use curly brackets it will highlight the start or the end point. and I personally also prefer curly brackets syntax.

Anyone know where I can get the solution?

Comment: A simple search/replace might work. Can't be too many other places in PHP where you'd see `): ` and `endif;`. Just S&R them to `{ ` and `}` respectively and see how mangled the code gets.

Comment: if we are working with a big php file replace like your way is kind of risky. I more prefer using regular expression way if someone can kindly show us.

Comment: I'd actually be interested in the reverse of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+H`

Search `):` and replace with `) {`

Search `endif;` and replace with `}`

Also go to `Source->Format`, you are done!

Comment: not really, some of the code that I have is something like
") :" ")<space><space>:", by using this way is more like manual way, I would prefer have an regular express ignore the space, and replace it. However, thanks for your solution :)

Comment: In that case you can use regex in search option. Check out this article: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/12/use-regular-expressions-for-search-and.html

Comment: Hi Otar, thanks for your reply, do you have the regex ? That would be helpful with that :)

Comment: I'm not a regex guru but it should be something like this: `^)/(.*)/:` or `^).*:`